# How to highlight specific packages before updating

Tags: terminal, package-management, aptitude

Whenever I update my Debiansystem I use sudo aptitude (update/upgrade) in my terminal.

This sometimes produces a long confusing list of upgradeable packages. Most of those are not of my interest. Certain packages are of my interest however (like manually installed or third party ones).

It would be neat to have certain packages (that I can define) highlighted in that list so I can check the changelog of those.

Is there a way to achieve this? Or is there a package manager that can "watch" packages for changes?

Comment: At least to highlight it in the output the following thread could be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/981601/2261442

Comment: Yes, with that I can write a mini shell script that just adds patterns to that command and then output aptitude upgrade via grep. You could write this as an answer or I wait for another answer. Thanks.

Comment: At first I wanted to write it as an answer but then I saw that you were also looking for a way to "watch" for those packages, I guess getting a notification of some sort?

Comment: Just highlighting that package x is also upgradeable. How that is achieved does not matter to me. For example if a package manager would use tags/flags to allow me to filter for my defined packages would be ok too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following one-liner will show look for the word `linux` in all upgradable packages, highlight it and specifically notify you (requires the `ack-grep` package):

```
 apt update &&
   apt list --upgradable | ack --color --passthru linux &&
   echo 'There is something of interest!'
```

(You might replace the last `echo` with e.g. `notify-send` or similar, see: https://superuser.com/questions/31917/is-there-a-way-to-show-notification-from-bash-script-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I needed to wait a day to test this. I combined this with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26275582/searching-multiple-patterns-words-with-ack . Works great